# Sum and Count of user quantity

Tags: mysql

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

I am struggling to write a query in which I want how many times a users have purchased a quanity and sum of total quantity of one users

Sample Entries

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

So my result should be

[image]

Comment: Use a `JOIN` to both tables on the joining column. `GROUP BY user_id`. And use aggregate `COUNT(*)` and `SUM(quantity)` in the result.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information to answer your question here. Specifically, what column in `Table2` holds the related field to `Table1`? As it stands, it's not possible to arrive to your example result based on the columns you've told us about.

Comment: @J.D. perhaps the name of the second column of table2, "table1_id", could be a clue?